# Secondary touch monitor not moving with the cursor but still pressing buttons (or emitting events for Qt app)

Tags: windows, qt, touchscreen, multiple-monitors

I intend to make an app for Windows in Qt with multi-monitor support, **one (secondary) monitor being touch**. I want one person to be able to work with the **touch screen independently** on a second person, which would be working on the main screen with mouse and keyboard.

I don't have the the touch monitor yet, so I don't know how it really works, but **I am afraid that touching the monitor would move the cursor** (mouse pointer), making the work with mouse very hard.

So my question:

> Is it possible somehow to make the touch screen not to affect the cursor in any way (not interrupting drag&drop counts, too), but still to be able to push buttons n' stuff, and that on either Windows or Qt level?

No buttons pushing, but generating QTouchEvents (or similar) would be sufficent, too.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: You'd have to coax the monitor's driver to act the way you want first. This has little to do with Qt until you get it working with plain WINAPI.